# openni_ros - xtion pro - network connection has been closed!

Tags: openni, xtion, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get some depth data out of the Xtion Pro.  I'm on ubuntu 10.0.4.  I'm using the latest version of openni_ros and I'm following the directions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch under **3. Quick Start** to the T.

Unfortunately, I don't see any data in rviz, and I get the following message in the console.  It looks like it can't detect my device?

```
[ INFO] [1314686850.673973496]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1314686850.674117789]: 1. device on bus 003:02 is a PrimeSense Device (600) from PrimeSense (1d27) with serial id ''
[ INFO] [1314686850.676183995]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1314686850.681652725]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @ /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_ros/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 61 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: The network connection has been closed!
```

Any ideas on what this closed network connection might be?  And how I might repair it? Any one else using an Xtion Pro experiencing similar issues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11057/openni_ros---xtion-pro---network-connection-has-been-closed!/) by [quantize](https://answers.ros.org/users/1010/quantize/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-08-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [quantize](https://answers.ros.org/users/1010/quantize/) on 2011-09-19**:
Yes, using Electric.  Yes running roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch.  Yes it is an Xtion pro.  Any additional info I could give to get help?

**Comment by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) on 2011-09-02**:
A couple clarifications: you're using Electric and getting this error following `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`? Also, your device is an Xtion Pro (no RGB camera) and not the new Xtion Pro Live? Following the openni_launch instructions, I'm able to use my Xtion Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. It seems that your system is confused between the Diamondback installation and the Electric installation. The last line of your error dump references Diamondback. Make sure your environment is set up correctly.

---

Originally posted by [prp](https://answers.ros.org/users/706/prp/) with karma: 118 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0